# Selenium web driver: search an image from HTML table and perform some operation if that is found

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver, Java & TestNG. I am trying to search for an image from an HTML table, and I need to click on some other button if that image is found. 
Eg:

1. There is a div, with table headers as
       Name Place Thing Alert
2. There is an alert image visible in fourth column, when some operation are performed.
3. So I wanted to search for that alert image, and click on click button if that alert image is found.

Here is the html code

```
<th scope="col">
  Detail
</th>

<th class="sortable" scope="col">

  <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('reprot5','test$DateScored')">
    Received
  </a>

</th>

<th scope="col">

  <th scope="col">
    Alert
</th>

<th class="report6" scope="col">
  Response
</th>

<th scope="col"/>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

  <tr class="reprot7">

    <td>
      test survey
    </td>

    <td>

      <span>
        Agent--Equiniti
      </span>

    </td>

    <td>

      <span>
        28 November 2013 10:47:59
      </span>

    </td>

    <td>

      <span/>

    </td>

    <td>

      <span>

        <img class="justprintingImg" style="padding-left:10px;" src="../icon_alert.gif"/>

      </span>

    </td>
```

Comment: Aruna: can you please share your HTML code...

Comment: </th>
<th scope="col">Detail</th>
<th class="sortable" scope="col">
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('reprot5','test$DateScored')">Received</a>
</th>
<th scope="col">
<th scope="col">Alert</th>
<th class="report6" scope="col"> Response</th>
<th scope="col"/>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="reprot7">
<td> test survey</td>
<td>
<span> Agent--Equiniti</span>
</td>
<td>
<span>28 November 2013 10:47:59</span>
</td>
<td>
<span/>
</td>
<td>
<span>
<img class="justprintingImg" style="padding-left:10px;" src="../icon_alert.gif"/>
</span>
</td>

Comment: I want to search for last .gif Image. and If found I want to click on Click buton

Answer (score 0):

Though not tested, but I think following will give you an idea for the same.

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='../icon_alert.gif"));
    if(image!=null){
        //button click event
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
Boolean bool=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='justprintingImg')).isDisplayed();
                                 (OR)
Boolean bool=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='../icon_alert.gif')).isDisplayed();

if(bool){
Click operation
}
```

Hope this helps you

-Ajay

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I tried both ways now,& even before I ask this question, but it is gives error No such element exception

Answer (score 0):

I've made a lot of assumptions here, but what I think you're looking for is the use of a try/catch block

```
try
{
  //Assuming there is only one row in this table, otherwise you'll need to modify the below to loop through each row

  WebElement alertImage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='justprintingImg']"));

  //Alert image is present, so do something with it...
  alertImage.click();

}
catch (NoSuchElementException nsee)
{
  //Alert image is not present, do nothing 
}

//continue on
```

Answer (score 0):

Images take time to load, it would be better if an `Explicit wait` is used to locate the image..

```
boolean is_image_present = false;
try
{
  new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("img.justprintingImg")));
  is_image_present = true;
}catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("image not present!!!");
}

if(is_image_present)
{
  //code to click on the button
}
```